# How to change the way that vim displays collapsed/folded lines

Tags: vim, code-folding

How can I change the way that vim displays those collapsed/folded lines? I would like it toshow hidden line numbers at line tail but not the head.  I have googled and searched vim wiki but found no hints.

[image: more pretty vim fold format]

The fold style is just like the right hand side of the pic.

Comment: After looking at "`:help fold-foldtext`" I don't think what you want is possible without patching the Vim core code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could play with the method described in [this blog post](http://dhruvasagar.com/2013/03/28/vim-better-foldtext):

```
function! NeatFoldText()
    let line = ' ' . substitute(getline(v:foldstart), '^\s*"\?\s*\|\s*"\?\s*{{' . '{\d*\s*', '', 'g') . ' '
    let lines_count = v:foldend - v:foldstart + 1
    let lines_count_text = '| ' . printf("%10s", lines_count . ' lines') . ' |'
    let foldchar = matchstr(&fillchars, 'fold:\zs.')
    let foldtextstart = strpart('+' . repeat(foldchar, v:foldlevel*2) . line, 0, (winwidth(0)*2)/3)
    let foldtextend = lines_count_text . repeat(foldchar, 8)
    let foldtextlength = strlen(substitute(foldtextstart . foldtextend, '.', 'x', 'g')) + &foldcolumn
    return foldtextstart . repeat(foldchar, winwidth(0)-foldtextlength) . foldtextend
endfunction

set foldtext=NeatFoldText()
```

There are [many](https://bitbucket.org/atimholt/spiffy_foldtext), [variants](https://gist.github.com/sjl/3360978), [actually](http://www.gregsexton.org/2011/03/improving-the-text-displayed-in-a-fold/); and there's even a [vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/writing-a-custom-fold-expression/) on that very subject.